# UML extensions for AOP

Tags: uml, aop

While full-blown AOP has not hit the mainstream yet, simpler versions of AOP based on interceptions, filters, annotations etc. certainly have.

It has been a while since I looked at UML standard and tools. So, I wonder what are the ways to represent AOP constructs in UML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dan,

This Wikipedia article: [Aspect-Oriented Software Development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_software_development#Aspect-oriented_modeling_and_design) has some models created using [Motorola WEAVR](http://www.jot.fm/issues/issue_2007_08/article3.pdf). WEAVR proposes an UML profile that works with class and state machine diagrams. A lot of work is being realized on Aspect-Oriented Modeling (AOM). You could look at [AOSD 2013 Conference](http://aosd.net/2013/) too.

Comment: Theme/UML is an important tool too.

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of profiles for defining aspect-oriented systems in UML. What I don't know is  whether any of them have been integrated into a well-known UML tool since most (all?) of them come from the research community.

Apart from just searching in google with the keywords "aspect profile UML", you can take a look at the papers published in the series of Aspect modeling workshops: http://www.aspect-modeling.org/